# Open Facebook link in app on mobile or in browser if FB app is not installed

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook's mobile app used to know how to open the url `http://facebook.com/<id_of_thing>` and it used to open that up to a specific photo in the app. What we discovered last week (11/6/15) was that the app still listens for that url pattern, but it doesn’t know how to open up to a specific photo (it opens up to the blank page.) If we send the full url of the photo to the user, something like `http://facebook.com/<pageid>/<album_id>_<photo_id>`, the Facebook app doesn’t listen for that url pattern. So it opens up in a browser instead.  How do I get a link sent to a user via text message or email to open up in the Facebook app on a mobile device?

Comment: The URL scheme for the native Facebook app is not a documented feature. Hence you cannot rely on its behaviour to be consistent.